# Convert 10,000+ JSON files into one single SQLite db?

Tags: python, database, json, google-app-engine, github-archive

Ok so I wanted to build a simple web app, that somehow would use githubarchive data. AT first I though of using the BigQuery database and it's API, however, my free quota would be over in just a day.

So, what I've done is download all 2012/2013 records from the site, and extracted them in a folder - now I have 10k+ json files than I want to use to get data for my app.

So what I want: Create a GAE (python) or Django app to visualize this data. For this, I need to convert the json files in to a database - I want to use SQLite but I'm not sure what's the best choice. I'm not sure if creating a DB is required at all, but that's what I can think of right now.

Anyone has any suggestions for me?

Comment: 1. Read in a JSON file. 2. INSERT into database. 3. Go to step 1.

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine is also not free beyond certain quota. I'm pretty sure that importing 10k+ Json files and then doing analytics will be well beyond the free quota.

Also, AppEngine has a very limited query language (no cross-entity queries, no joins, single inequality filter) which will prevent you doing any meaningful analytics. Go with BigQuery and swallow the cost or just do the analytics on your own machine and then export the stats to GAE for presentation.

Both GAE and BQ are a fast massively-parallel highly-available services, which you would want to use for a production applications. If you are on a budget and do not need the high-availability, go with an [affordable VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing).

Comment: Well the thing is the analytics is dynamic. For example, a user enters a language and I would return a list of, say, 100 GH users that have repos in this language. This is a highly simplified example of what I want to do. Using BQ will be extremely expensive for me since each query takes about 15GB of processing. That's why I want to store the data with myself, and then use that instead.

Comment: How about using the DB with Django? I can try and convert the files into a SQLite database, use `inspectdb` to write models for it. Is that practical?

Comment: Why do you say SQLite? GAE does not use SQLite. Local dev server uses SQLite under the hood as embedded database, but there is no SQLite in production.

Comment: DB on GAE has very limited query, I'd advise against using it for raw analytics.

Comment: Not necessarily SQlite, but any other db as well. I'll try to build a db with the json files I have and then use it with Django.

Comment: Sure, locally. But GAE comes with it's own datastore which you need to use. No way to use any other/external database on GAE.

Comment: How easy would it be deploy my app using my own db on any other django-compatible host given that the db would be huge?

Comment: @KaranGoel  Did you succeed? I'm facing a similar requirement now for an academic research.

Comment: @KaranGoel Did you ever find a way to analyze the large amount of data? I'm facing nearly exactly the same predicament for the GitHub Data Challenge

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints it seems your best bet is to process the files on your local machine and save the query-able results to AppEngine [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) and from there present them to the user.  Depending on how well you are able to process the data to prepared query-able results you could also consider [Cloud-SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide) (MySQL).

Some proposed steps:

1. Determine exactly what you want to show or allow to queried.  From that information then determine what format of data would enable it to be done most easily.

   - From your example about 100GH users with a repo in a language. Then create a table that has the user, language, and possibly some other fields such as number of repos.
2. Process the data files you have and write to the tables and fields you've defined in 1.

   - You'll have to decide what's the best way to do this in your case.  It might be that you write a simple app that you run locally which parses each file, tracks some values in memory and writes them when done to the server.  It could also be that you import to a local database server (MySQl, PostgreSQL, ...) and then query it and then write to the server or run some map reduce jobs.
   - Once you have the data if you app has an API you could put it on AppEngine with that, if not maybe Remote-API is a quick solution.
3. Design your front end web site that then performs the queries you planned for in 1.  Generally Those queries should be relatively inexpensive and simple if you've planned ahead well.

Of course there compromises with this solution and it's not going to be trivial to add ah-hoc queries that you didn't prepare easily (some re-processing and updating of data likely).  However hopefully you're able to plan your needs well and you can serve a reasonable number of requests without things getting slow or expensive.